# Cant update password with devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with a password, password_confirmation and current_password fields, and when i try to update it, it doesn't change the password in the db. I only want to update the password with the current password, and update the other fields such as name, email and lastname without the current password...I've been strugling a lot with this, and i don't know where i'm wrong...The field of email, name and lastname can be updated but the password not, it only redirects me to the root page!

This is Model :

```
 attr_accessible :name,:email,:lastname,:password,:password_confirmation,:current_password,:remember_me

 validates :name,:presence=>true,
              :length=>{:maximum=>50}

 validates :lastname,:presence=>true,
                  :length=>{:maximum=>50}


 def update_with_password(params={})
    current_password = params.delete(:current_password)


    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end 

   result =  if valid_password?(current_password) 
     update_attributes(params)
    else
      self.attributes = params
      self.valid?
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end 

    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end      

  def update_without_password(params, *options)
    params.delete(:password)
    params.delete(:password_confirmation)

    result = update_attributes(params, *options)
    clean_up_passwords
    result
  end
```

This is my registrations controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController 
def edit
@user = current_user
end

def update
@user = User.find(current_user.id)

if @user.update_without_password(params[:user])  
  # Sign in the user by passing validation in case his password changed
  sign_in @user, :bypass => true
  flash[:success]="Profile updated"
  redirect_to edit_user_registration_path(current_user.id)
else
  render "edit"
end
```

end
end

My passwords controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def edit
@user = current_user
end

def update
@user = current_user
# raise params.inspect
  if @user.update_with_password(params[:user])
    sign_in @user,:bypass=>true
    flash[:success]="You already changed your pass"  
  redirect_to edit_user_password_path(current_user.id)
else
  render :edit
end
end 
end
```

My passwords edit view:

```
<h2>Change your password</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>
<%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>
<div><%= f.label :current_password, "Old password" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :current_password %></div>

<div><%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %></div>
<div><%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>  
<div><%= f.submit "Change my password" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => "devise/links" %>
```

I would appreciate some help i been stuck in these for a while...

Answer (score 0):

You don't save your user in your Controller.

You can do that in your `update_without_password` method or in your controller.

```
  def update_with_password(params={})
    current_password = params.delete(:current_password)


    if params[:password].blank?
      params.delete(:password)
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank?
    end 

   result =  if valid_password?(current_password) 
     update_attributes(params)
    else
      self.attributes = params
      self.valid?
      self.errors.add(:current_password, current_password.blank? ? :blank : :invalid)
      false
    end 

    clean_up_passwords
    result
    save
  end
```